# How to get my list of contacts in Microsoft Teams Toolkit for React?

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I am building a `Teams` extension using the `Teams Toolkit` and `React`.

I would like to access my `Teams` contacts (maybe get them as an array or some other collection) and display them in my extension.

I have read somewhere that the only way to do this is through the `Microsoft Graph API`, and that there aren't really `Teams` specific contacts, but that they come from multiple places within the `Microsoft 365` ecosystem and possibly elsewhere.

Is `Microsoft Graph API` really the ONLY way to get a list of contacts into my extension? If it's not the ONLY way, is it the best way? What are other ways to access my contacts if any?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Microsoft Graph API is the primary and recommended way to access and manage data in Microsoft 365, which includes Teams contacts. Teams contacts are indeed not specific to Teams but are part of the broader Microsoft 365 ecosystem. 

Please refer these Graph API docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http